# Best way for ETL from a file to MySQL

Tags: etl

What is the best and faster way for ETL from a huge file of records to inserting those transformed records in MySQL table ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tools to do that, you can use SSIS, Talend, Informatica, etc..

Also you can create you own etl process using python, golang, or any other language.

Another simple and minimal tool to do that is [Dixer](https://dixer.stgo.do) I'm the main developer and is a tool to do etl process fast for big files and support big relational databases without the need to download dependencies.